# how to create custom cell in tableView (swipe cell)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I want to create one application that in self has tableview.this tableView show has many cell in self.I want when push right to left in one cell display another page in cell (like yahoo mail that when push right to left show 5 status : favorit,delete,...)

I want create this but I dont know about it and I searching in google but I dont found anything.

please guide and tell me how to create tableview that all cell have one ability : (when push right to left show another page in cell place with 5 button like yahoo mail app)

Comment: You can make custom cell in which cell's contentView to contain all the buttons you need.

Comment: my friend if I to create custom cell but how to swipe cell and show another page in cell???

Comment: you can add UISwipeGestureRecognizer to cell and then when swipe handled exchange current cell content view subview with another subview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend see this page. I hope this help you.

http://code4app.net/ios/Side-Swipe-TableView/4f68194e6803fa3449000001